# Why can my Azure PowerShell Task script find a module using find-module but not with import-module?

Tags: azure, powershell, tfs

I've been having difficulty importing the community module `PoshRSJob` in PowerShell script through an Azure PowerShell task. It keeps giving me this error:

> The specified module 'PoshRSJob' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

What I did to attempt to fix this was install another module called `InstallModuleFromGitHub`, which I used to directly install `PoshRSJob` using the command `Find-Module PoshRSJob | Install-ModuleFromGitHub`. I built with the script only installing the `InstallModuleFromGitHub` and the `PoshRSJob` modules (and everything else commented out), and it succeeded. The rest of the script calls functions that call `Import-Module PoshRSJob`, so, if the module installed correctly, everything else should have worked. Well, despite the module supposedly installing successfully, the build failed with the same error as before. When I call `Find-Module -Name PoshRSJob`, the build successfully locates it. But when I call `Import-Module -Name PoshRSJob`, the build fails and gives me the error again.

These are the console logs from the failed build:

```
******************************************************************************
Import-Module -Name C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager\AzureRM.Profile\AzureRM.Profile.psd1 -Global
Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant a9691d3f-49e3-46a8-8b23-ddad274d0523 -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential
Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId 4242fd68-ea68-4c3c-869a-43269a2b8271 -TenantId a9691d3f-49e3-46a8-8b23-ddad274d0523
& '\\neenah-san1\KTS-Dev\temp\Noah\LoadTestingTests\StartVM.ps1'
Version    Name                                Repository           Description
-------    ----                                ----------           -----------
1.7.4.4    PoshRSJob                           PSGallery            Module d...
The specified module 'PoshRSJob' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: AzurePowerShell
******************************************************************************
System.Exception: Task AzurePowerShell failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.Run(IJobContext jobContext, IJobRequest job, IJobExtension jobExtension, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
Worker Worker-9aa3b65a-1416-4840-a9fa-44dce695db94 finished running job 9aa3b65a-1416-4840-a9fa-44dce695db94
******************************************************************************
Finishing Build
```

This is the relevant code from `StartVM.ps1` that caused those logs:

```
# import modules
Install-Module -Name InstallModuleFromGitHub -RequiredVersion 0.3 -Force -Scope CurrentUser
Find-Module PoshRSJob | Install-ModuleFromGitHub -Verbose
Import-Module '\\neenah-san1\TSbuild\Deployment\Tools\PowerShell\Azure\JJK.TS.Azure.psm1' -Force -Prefix 'TS' -Verbose 

Find-Module -Name PoshRSJob
Import-Module -Name PoshRSJob
```

Function from `\JJK.TS.Azure.psm1\` that is called in `StartVM`, which has the command `Import-Module PoshRSJob`:

```
function Start-AzureVM {
    <#
    .synopsis
    Starts one or more VMs using background threads
    .example
    Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName 'TS-LoadTest-TST' | Start-AzureVM
    #>
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true)]

    param (
      [Alias("Name")]
      [Parameter( Mandatory=$true,
                  ValueFromPipeline=$false,
                  ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
                    [string]$VMName,
      [Parameter( Mandatory=$true,
                  ValueFromPipeline=$false,
                  ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
                    [string]$ResourceGroupName,
      [Parameter( Mandatory=$false,
                  ValueFromPipeline=$false,
                  ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$false)]
                    [string]$SubscriptionName,
      [Parameter( Mandatory=$false,
                  ValueFromPipeline=$false,
                  ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$false)]
                    [PSCredential]$Credential
    )

    begin {

      $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

      # import community module to handle powershell runspaces
      Import-Module 'PoshRSJob'
```

How can the agent simultaneously find and not be able to find the module?
 Why hasn't it been able to find `PoshRSJob` in the first place?

[EDIT] I've tried using `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name PoshRSJob | Import-Module` to pipe it to `Import-Module`, and I don't really know how to interpret the results. It looks like the task imports `PoshRSJob` successfully, and then completely ignores it, says it can't find the module, and fails. I'm thinking there has to be a disconnect between the repository `PoshRSJob` is being stored in and the repository the agent is looking in.. How would I be able to remedy that if this were the case? (for brevity sake I only included the logs created by these two commands: `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name PoshRSJob | Import-Module -Force -Verbose` and `Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName 'TS-LoadTest-TST' | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'vstc'} | Start-TSAzureVM` )

```
2019-06-05T20:26:23.7173881Z ##[debug]Loading module from path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PoshRSJob\PoshRSJob\Scripts\TabExpansion.ps1'.
2019-06-05T20:26:23.7223881Z ##[debug]Dot-sourcing the script file 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PoshRSJob\PoshRSJob\Scripts\TabExpansion.ps1'.
2019-06-05T20:26:23.7463881Z ##[debug]Loading module from path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PoshRSJob\PoshRSJob\PoshRSJob.psm1'.
2019-06-05T20:26:24.1043881Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Get-RSJob'.
2019-06-05T20:26:24.1063881Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Receive-RSJob'.
2019-06-05T20:26:24.1083881Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Remove-RSJob'.
2019-06-05T20:26:24.1093881Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Start-RSJob'.
2019-06-05T20:26:24.1113881Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Stop-RSJob'.
2019-06-05T20:26:24.1133881Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Wait-RSJob'.
2019-06-05T20:26:24.1153881Z ##[debug]Importing alias 'gsj'.
2019-06-05T20:26:24.1173881Z ##[debug]Importing alias 'rmsj'.
2019-06-05T20:26:24.1193881Z ##[debug]Importing alias 'rsj'.
2019-06-05T20:26:24.1213881Z ##[debug]Importing alias 'spsj'.
2019-06-05T20:26:24.1233881Z ##[debug]Importing alias 'ssj'.
2019-06-05T20:26:24.1243881Z ##[debug]Importing alias 'wsj'.
2019-06-05T20:26:24.2903881Z ##[error]The specified module 'PoshRSJob' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
2019-06-05T20:26:28.9823881Z Finishing task: AzurePowerShell
2019-06-05T20:26:28.9873881Z ##[error]System.Exception: Task AzurePowerShell failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
2019-06-05T20:26:28.9873881Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.Run(IJobContext jobContext, IJobRequest job, IJobExtension jobExtension, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
```

Comment: I tried the `Get-Module` call as well. Specifically i used `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name PoshRSJob. This is the console result from that test:

Comment: ```ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands     
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------     
Script     1.7.4.4    PoshRSJob                           {Get-RSJob, Receiv...
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: AzurePowerShell
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56465276/edit) your question to include information like that, rather than adding it as a comment.

Comment: When you call the `Start-AzureVM` function, is it in the same session/runspace? I don't know if we have enough context here to fully help. If you can find it with `Get-Module -list PoshRSJob`, why not just pipe that to `Import-Module`?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician It is. So I'm running StartVM, which imports the JJK.TS.Azure module, and that has functions which call `import-module PoshRSJob`, and those functions are used in StartVM in order to, well, start the vm. I will try to pipe it to import-module; I'm kinda learning PowerShell as I go, I think the command would be: `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name PoshRSJob | Import-Module` ?

Comment: Yep, that should do it.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I think it worked but also it didn't. Look at my edit, the agent clearly imports `PoshRSJob`, but then it can't find it when `Start-AzureVM` calls `Import-Module PoshRSJob`. Could the module be installing/importing in the wrong directory? If so, how could I change where it's being installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! `Install-ModuleFromGitHub` ended up installing `PoshRSJob` in a repository that the agent couldn't reach. I uninstalled the module by means of `Uninstall-Module -Name PoshRSJob -AllVersions -Force`. Then, I tried to use just a normal `Install-Module` command. This wasn't working before, which is part of the reason I was trying to use `Install-ModuleFromGitHub`, but it works now for some reason. So anyways, after calling `Install-Module -Name PoshRSJob -Force`, I imported it using `Import-Module -Name PoshRSJob`.
I tested by building through tfs, and it not only was able to find `PoshRSJob`, but it managed to execute a lot of code before something else broke! But that isn't relevant to this specific question so I'll leave it at that.